# Approximating Fresnel integrals with standard functions

Tags: calculus, approximation, interpolation, fresnel-integrals

I would like to approximate the Fresnel S and Fresnel C with standard functions.

I've started with the $ S(x) $ function:

$$ approxS(x) = sgn(x) * \left ( sgn(x)* \left ( \frac{ \sin( \frac{x^2}{2}  ) }{x} \right) + 0.5 \right ) $$

The result looks like this:

[image: approx]

This is the FresnelS function:

[image: fresnelS]

The difference ( $ approxS(x) - S(x) $ ):

[image: difference]

What do I wrong? How could I approximate it better?

Comment: well to be fair to yourself, the error looks worse than it is due to the scale of your axes.

Comment: over what range of values of x?

Comment: $ x \in \mathbb{R} $

Comment: You want one formula that is accurate everywhere?

Comment: I am looking for a forula, which can approximate the Fresnel function everywhere as close, as possible

Comment: But not too close, to keep the formula simple

Answer (score 2):

According to
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral,
for large $x$,
$S(x)
=\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}\left(\dfrac{sign(x)}{2}
-(1+O(x^{-4}))\left(\dfrac{\cos(x^2)}{x\sqrt{2\pi}}
+\dfrac{\sin(x^2)}{x^3\sqrt{8\pi}} \right)\right)
$
and
$C(x)
=\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}\left(\dfrac{sign(x)}{2}
+(1+O(x^{-4}))\left(\dfrac{\sin(x^2)}{x\sqrt{2\pi}}
+\dfrac{\cos(x^2)}{x^3\sqrt{8\pi}} \right)\right)
$.

You can get the
direct power series
(good for small $x$)
by expanding the integral
term-by-term.

It might be interesting
to see how close these are.